# 'Eden space' name origin in Garbage Collection

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm-hotspot

In Garbage Collection terminology, why is it called 'Eden Space'?

Just like that. I'm still getting familiar with the terminology and I cannot understand why it has such name.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Eden space is where objects are created. Life for them is all happy but eventually they're chased out by a cherub into the wilderness of the young and later the old generation.

They are never allowed back in Eden space, they have to stay in the rough world of continuous tenuring until the Grim Collector comes for them.

However, unlike the original Eden, it is possible to die there. Well, I guess all metaphors break down under closer scrutiny.

Comment: Other GC implementations call this a nursery.

Comment: @Tobu I wouldn't even think of trying to extend the metaphor to cover that. :)

Answer (score 8):

It's an allusion to the [garden of Eden](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_of_Eden). It's also called "creation space." Adam and Eve were, according to Genesis, put in Eden. When they ate the fruit from the tree of knowledge, they were kicked out of the garden.

Comment: Sure, I got that part figured out. Can you elaborate on why?:)

Answer (score 4):

New objects are allocated memory in the Eden Space memory pool (as in created in Eden)

If they live long enough, they get kicked out.

Comment: As in (paraphrasing the Wikipedia entry) 'The Garden of Eden being the place where the first objects, lived after they were created by God.' ?

Comment: Pretty much. Though they don't have to eat an apple to get kicked out.

Comment: Actually, it was not an apple. Just fruit